# Is the memory assigned to a strong property released as soon as the property is set to nil?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I would like to know how to release a strong property/iVar. I would like to clarify why I intend to do this. I own an object via any one of these declaration:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject 
     @property (readwrite, nonatomic) MyObject *hugeObject;
@end
```

OR

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
     MyObject *hugeObject;
}
@end
```

I create this object in some method, I use it in another and so on

```
- (void)someMethod {
     hugeObject = [[MyObject alloc] init];
}

- (void)someOtherMethod {
     hugeObject = //some function call which returns a MyObject object
     //do something with hugeObject
}
```

Now, `someOtherMethod` is called several times and each time `hugeObject` has to store a new value. I no longer need the previous value and since its heavy, I would like to get rid of it. So I modified `someOtherMethod` in this way

```
- (void)someOtherMethod {
     hugeObject = //some function call which returns a MyObject object
     //do something with hugeObject
     hugeObject = nil;
}
```

I don't want to wait till dealloc, so assigned it to `nil`. But the memory usage still rises and only decreases when the program ends.

So, here is what I am confused with:

- Is the memory assigned to a strong property released as soon as the property is set to nil?
- or is the memory released only when ARC calls dealloc on its own ?

---

**PROBLEM IDENTIFIED :** Strong references pointing to object.

**SOLUTION :**

I solved it by placing all the `strong` property/iVar in `@autoreleasepool` (as sugessted in the accepted answer) so that they are released at the end of the current run loop. Debugging helped like charm (as sugessted by Sulthan).

**NOTE :** Make sure the `@autoreleasepool` is a locally scoped pool or else this would prevent the memory release you expect – as there will still be a strong reference.

**LESSON LEARNED :**

- When `nil` is assigned you can be sure about only one thing. The object will get sent either a `release` or an `autorelease` message. **ARC doesn't guarantee which one**.
- Provided that there are **no more strong references pointing to the object, the memory will get released either immediately (the `release` case) or at the end of the current loop (the `autorelease` case).**

Comment: The question is a bit ambiguous since you say "property" but you are not using any Objective-C properties in your example.

Comment: ARC will send a `release` message to the object when you `nil` the strong pointer to it, but if something else has a strong pointer to the same object, then the object won't be deallocated yet.

Comment: @PhillipMills It was a silly mistake. Please check the edited version

Comment: @JoshCaswell Will ARC send `release` message instantly when `nil` is encountered or will it wait for the scope to complete? Also ARC will send `release` to `hugeObject` right? If so, then what happens to the chunk of memory it was pointing to before `nil` was assigned to it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning `nil` to a strong variable does indicate that you no longer need the object the variable is referencing, and *provided no other strong references to the object exist* ARC will dispose of the object quickly, if not immediately.

Your object is *probably* (see end) referenced by the *autorelease pool*, which is essentially a historical artefact left over from pre-ARC days, and this would prevent the memory release you expect – as there is still a strong reference.

Primarily to enable mere humans to cope with manual reference counting (MRC) the autorelease pool accepts ownership of objects till some point in the not too distant future, at which time it relinquishes that ownership. Use of the autorelease pools simplifies MRC but in the days of ARC it is not *required* but still exists - largely as plenty of existing code relies on it.

The usual "not too distant future" is the next iteration of the event loop, but you can introduce local scopes which when exited will relinquish ownership of all objects added to the pool during that scope. To do this you can change your code to:

```
- (void)someOtherMethod
{
   @autoreleasepool // make a locally scope pool
   {
      hugeObject = //some function call which returns a MyObject object
      //do something with hugeObject
      hugeObject = nil;
   }
}
```

As stated above, it is only *probable* that your object is in the autorelease pool, if the above does not solve your problem then you have another strong reference to your object lurking somewhere...

HTH

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. But what if I need the prebious value of `hugeObject` until it gets a new value(most probably in the next run loop) i.e only when a new value is attained, the previous value should be deallocated. Apart from ignoring the line `hugeObject = nil` to be put at the end, what else should I do?

Comment: When the runloop goes around any reference to your object in the autorelease pool will be dropped. You can only have a problem if (a) you do a lot of work per event; (b) your object gets placed in the pool *before* you enter a local pool (`@autoreleasepool`); and (c) you want the object to really be released ASAP when set to `nil`. If you are sure such a situation can exist then one approach is to ensure there is only one reference to your object by having a "manager" class hold it and allowing multiple references only to the manager. Your manager can then drop the object when requested.

Answer (score 2):

When `nil` is assigned you can be sure about only one thing. The object will get sent either a `release` or an `autorelease` message. ARC doesn't guarantee which one.

Provided that there are no more strong references pointing to the object, the memory will get released either immediately (the `release` case) or at the end of the current loop (the `autorelease` case) - that means within a fraction of a second.

When some memory is not released, usually that means that there is another strong reference holding the object or the object itself doesn't release memory properly.

In your case it's not very clear how do you even inspect whether the object has been released or not. The simplest check is using a log in `dealloc`:

```
- (void)dealloc {
   NSLog(@"Huge object has been removed from memory");
}
```

Note that the amount of memory allocated to the application is not equal to the amount of memory actually used by the application. If you want real info about memory allocations, use Memory Profiler in Inspector.

Answer (score -1):

Assigning nil will send a release message immediately. However, "some function call which returns a MyObject object" will likely return an autoreleased object, which will have a retain count from the autorelease pool until the pool disappears. You get around that by creating your own autorelease pool.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you. Could you please elaborate with some code.

Comment: "Assigning nil will send a release message immediately" ARC does not guarantee that.

Comment: Part of this answer is wrong--the rest is confusing.

Answer (score -1):

""Is the memory assigned to a strong property released as soon as the property is set to nil ?""

Probably. It should get released in the NSAutoReleasePool. Here is some information about the auto release pool and how often it runs
From Apple's Docs on NSAutoreleasePool:

> The Application Kit creates an autorelease pool on the main thread at
>   the beginning of every cycle of the event loop, and drains it at the
>   end, thereby releasing any autoreleased objects generated while
>   processing an event.